# C++: Does using dereference to change value of a variable result in that variable pointing to a different memory block?

Tags: c++, pointers, variables, variable-assignment, definition

I have a simple program

```c
int main()
{
    
    int a = 1; // variable declaration
    printf("a before: %d \n", a); // a is 1
    int* b = &a; // pointer declaration - get the memory address of variable `a` with the `&` reference opeartor
    *b = 2; // dereference to access data contained the memory block of variable `a` via the the `*` dereference operator
    printf("a after : %d", a); // a becomes 2
    return 0;
}
```

I wonder which mental model is correct:

1. assume variable `a` points to the memory address `100000f91` at which the data `int 1` is stored. By doing this assignment `*b = 2` we change the content/data from `int 1` to `int 2` but the data is still in the original memory address i.e. `100000f91`.
2. By doing this assignment `*b = 2`, we change where the variable `a` point from the memory address `100000f91` to somewhere else e.g. `100000f92` at which the new data `int 2` is stored

Please feel free to correct me if I am wrong here. whichever the mental model is correct, I wonder if the same mental model can still apply when we pass `a` by reference to a function as in

```
void fn(int* b) {}
```

Comment: `a` is a _scalar_ and _not_ a _pointer_. So, it might be clearer if we rephrase: _assume variable `a` **points to** the memory address `100000f91`_  --> _assume variable `a` **is loaded at** the memory address `100000f91`_

Comment: #1 is the correct "mental model"

Comment: thanks for point that out @CraigEstey. Interesting maybe because I am just illiterate - this is my first time hearing that a variable is loaded at the some memory address.  But I think that makes a lot of sense. Can I also say that  variable `a` is/represents the memory address `100000f91`? also what about the word `reference` - can I say a variable references some data or it only applies when the variable is a pointer type?

Answer (score 3):

The variable `a` is not moved through the memory. The memory for the variable `a` is allocated as soon as it is defined.

The variable `a` points nowhere. It is designed to store an object of the type `int`.

It is the pointer `b` that stores the address of the variable `a`

```
int* b = &a;
```

So dereferencing the pointer we get an access to the memory allocated for the variable `a` and can change the stored object in this memory.

Here is a demonstration program that can help to make understanding easy.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( void )
{
    int a = 1;

    printf( "The address of the variable a is %p\n", ( void * )&a );

    int *b = &a;

    printf( "The address stored in the variable b is %p\n", ( void * )b );

    *b = 2;

    printf( "After the assignment the address of the variable a is %p\n", ( void * )&a );
}
```

The program output might look like

```
The address of the variable a is 006FF9D4
The address stored in the variable b is 006FF9D4
After the assignment the address of the variable a is 006FF9D4
```

As you can see after the assignment

```
    *b = 2;
```

the address of the variable `a` was not changed. It is the value that is stored in the memory occupied by the variable `a` that was changed.

You may consider a variable as a named extent of memory designed to store objects of the specified type used to declare the variable.

Comment: thanks for the reply. "The variable `a` points nowhere. It is designed to store an object of the type int." I wonder how exactly it "stores" the type `int`, like it is more accurate to say that variable `a` IS the address at which its value is stored? Please correct me if I am wrong

Comment: @Joji The variable a has an address where it is placed in the memory but it is designed to store an object of the type int.

Answer (score 2):

The address of a variable never changes during its lifetime.

This means that changing a variable's value, either directly:

```
a = 2;
```

Or indirectly:

```
b = &a;
*b = 2;
```

Never changes its address.  So your first mental model is correct.

Also, this statement is incorrect:

> assume variable a points to the memory address

`a` is not a pointer type so it does not point to an address.  Like all variables, it *has* an address that does not change.

Comment: thanks for the answer! "a is not a pointer type so it does not point to an address." I thought a pointer type would contain an address? because you retrieve the address from a variable and store it as the value to a pointer type like `int* b = &a`. Or I guess a variable IS the address at which its value is stored? is this more accurate?

Comment: @Joji Yes, a variable is essentially an alias for some block of memory, and the `&` operator gives you the starting address of that memory.

Comment: Another followup question if you don't mind: 
"The address of a variable never changes during its lifetime." I thought it would change its address if we reassign a different value to it? e.g. `int a = 1; a = 2;` are we still rewriting the same memory space or we are switching to a different memory block?

Comment: @Joji When you assign a value to a variable, you're changing the value at the variable's address.

Comment: @Joji Think of a variable as a house.  Then then address of a variable is like the street address of the house, and the value of a variable is like what is inside of the house .

Comment: Thanks so much! Can we say variable `a` **references** to some value or an address of some memory block when it is not a pointer type?